# JavaScript - logical issue with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to generate an invoice based on the array of orders and outlets, to do that I have to go through outlets array and get the `comission` as well as some other information and based on it I loop through the `orders` array in order to do the necessary calculations; however it seems that I have a logical issue as I am trying to get the values needed on `outlets` array which has a length of 2 and the length of `orders` array is 3 so the `orders` array is always not fully executed but stops at the second index.

The question : What should I do in order to list/calculate the final invoice for each store (id) ?

Live code to debug : https://playcode.io/597316/

Here is the code :

```
  var finalAmount = 0;
  var itemsProcessed = 0;

  async function dodo() {
  try {
     const orders = {
    Items: [  {
      outletId: 2,
      percentage: 20,
      amountUsed: 0,
      amountEntered: 100,
    },
    {
      outletId: 2,
      percentage: 20,
      amountUsed: 0,
      amountEntered: 100,

    },
    {
      outletId: 1,
      percentage: 10,
      amountUsed: 0,
      amountEntered: 300,
    }],
    Count: 1
    };


    let outlets = {
  Items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Test Shop',
      percentage: 10,
      commission: 5,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Test 2 Shop',
      percentage: 20,
      commission: 5,
    }
  ],
  Count: 2,
  ScannedCount: 2
};

    for (var i = 0; i < outlets.Items.length; i++) {
      if (orders.Count > 0) {

        orders.Items.forEach(order => {
          finalAmount += parseFloat((order.amountEntered - (order.amountEntered * (outlets.Items[i].commission + outlets.Items[i].percentage) / 100)).toFixed(2));
        },itemsProcessed++);
      }

      //itemsProcessed seems to stop at 2 because outlets.Items.length = 2

       //Never goes inside because orders.Items.length > itemsProcessed
      if (finalAmount > 0 && itemsProcessed === orders.Items.length) {
        //Create Invoice
        console.log('Generate invoice with an amount of ', finalAmount);
        finalAmount = 0;

      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error ', err);
  }
  }

  dodo();
```

Comment: You didn't indicate what was wrong, and you didn't ask any questions.

Comment: You can see inside the code :   //Never goes inside because orders.Items.length > itemsProcessed

Comment: You seem to understand what is wrong with the code.  What do you need to do to change the behavior if that is not what you want?

Comment: `itemsProcessed++` is executed in the loop that iterates over `outlets.Items`, not inside `orders.Items.forEach`. So yes, it will never be `> 2`. But `orders.Items.forEach` will still iterate over all elements in that array.

Comment: @FelixKling I've modified the question: What should I do in order to list/calculate the final invoice for each store (id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing puzzle here is matching the `outletId` in Orders array with `id` in Outlets array. The solution should look like the following :

```
    for (var i = 0; i < outlets.Items.length; i++) {
  if (orders.Count > 0) {
    orders.Items.forEach(order => {
      if(order.id === outlets.Items[i].id) {
          finalAmount += parseFloat((order.amountEntered - (order.amountEntered * (outlets.Items[i].commission + outlets.Items[i].percentage) / 100)).toFixed(2));
      }
    });
  }

   //Never goes inside because orders.Items.length > itemsProcessed
  if (finalAmount > 0) {
    //Create Invoice
    console.log('Generate invoice with an amount of ', finalAmount);
    finalAmount = 0;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `itemsProcessed++` statement as a parameter to the forEach function, instead of using it in the forEach loop like you probably intended to do.

The forEach function is called twice, and so itemsProcessed is incremented twice.